# Error : Index parameter out of range

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, combobox, primary-key

I want to insert primary key of selected item of combo box

but I got this error `Parameter index out of range(12 > number of parameter which is 0)`".

I really don't know how to fix this.

**Here is my code:**

```
String valueTrainer = "kosong";
try
{
   String sql2 = "Insert into ahli (MemberID, TrainerID, Name, ICNumber, Address, Nationality,"
                        + "PhoneNumber, Email, EmergencyPerson, EmergencyContact, DateReg, MemberTypeID) "
                        + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";


                pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);

                pst.setString(1, MemberIDTextField.getText());
                pst.setString(2, valueTrainer);
                pst.setString(3, NameTextField.getText());
                pst.setString(4, jTextField1.getText());
                pst.setString(5, AddressTextArea.getText());

                //Nationality combo box
                String nationalityList = NationalityComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                pst.setString(6, nationalityList);

                pst.setString(7, PhoneNumberTextField.getText());
                pst.setString(8, EmailTextField.getText());
                pst.setString(9, EmerContactPersonTextField.getText());
                pst.setString(10, EmerContactNumberTextField.getText());

                //Date Chooser
                pst.setString(11, ((JTextField)MemberDateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());

                //membertype combobox
                // problem start from here, I think..
                String memberTypeList = MemberTypeComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String sql1  ="Select MemberTypeID from jeniskeahlian where Type = '"+memberTypeList+"' " ;
                pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);

                rs = pst.executeQuery();

                while(rs.next()){

                    String memberType = rs.getString("MemberTypeID");
                    pst.setString(12, memberType);

               }

                pst.execute();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New member has been added");

            } catch (SQLException | HeadlessException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
```

Comment: you're using the same pst object to retrieve the membertypeid and to perform the insert. Review your logic...retrieve the membertypeid first, then create the insert statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `pst` properly.

*same named reference* on prepared statement can not be used on different sql statement unless one is used and closed properly. Prepare, set, execute, close on one statement, and then repeat the same on another statement.

**Change your code as below**.

```
try
{
   String memberTypeList = MemberTypeComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
   String sql1  ="Select MemberTypeID 
                    from jeniskeahlian 
                   where Type = ? " ;
   pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
   pst.setString( 1, memberTypeList );

   rs = pst.executeQuery();
   String memberType = "";
   while(rs.next()){
      memberType = rs.getString("MemberTypeID");
   }
   rs.close();
   pst.close();

   String sql2 = "Insert into ahli (MemberID, TrainerID, Name, 
                                    ICNumber, Address, Nationality,
                                    PhoneNumber, Email, EmergencyPerson, 
                                    EmergencyContact, DateReg, MemberTypeID)
                  values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

   pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);

   pst.setString(1, MemberIDTextField.getText());
   pst.setString(2, valueTrainer);
   pst.setString(3, NameTextField.getText());
   pst.setString(4, jTextField1.getText());
   pst.setString(5, AddressTextArea.getText());

   //Nationality combo box
   String nationalityList = NationalityComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
   pst.setString(6, nationalityList);

   pst.setString(7, PhoneNumberTextField.getText());
   pst.setString(8, EmailTextField.getText());
   pst.setString(9, EmerContactPersonTextField.getText());
   pst.setString(10, EmerContactNumberTextField.getText());

   //Date Chooser
   pst.setString(11, ((JTextField)MemberDateChooser
                                 .getDateEditor()
                                 .getUiComponent()).getText());
   pst.setString(12, memberType);

   pst.execute();

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New member has been added");

} // try
```

Answer (score 0):

While your insert statement seems properly populated, in the while-loop you rare trying to execute a select statement which has no parameters, so that `pst.setString(12,memberType)` fails.

```
String sql1  ="Select MemberTypeID from jeniskeahlian where Type = '"+memberTypeList+"' " ; //no ? in this query
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you execute the query you should have set all the values for all the parameters.

Comment: Better use a different statement for getting the membertypeids.